# VB program free freezes but still responds?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio

I have a winforms program written in visual Studio, coded in visual basic.

The main part of the program is a while loop that sends out serial commands, writes data to sql, does  basic arithmetic, and updates controls on my form.  I have this while  loop in a background workers do work sub so that the controls can be updated from the background worker sub, while it is still running. After awhile of running, my form will freeze up, while halfway through updating several text boxes. However, the background worker continues to run, the sql data still  gets written, and most curiously clicking a button on the form does what it is supposed to, even though we can't see that the button was pressed.

I can't think of anything that would cause behavior like this, where visually the form is frozen, but all the controls still respond.

Comment: Sign of a fire-hose problem, invoking from the worker thread faster than the UI can keep up.  Should be noticeable from Task Manager, you should see it burning 100% core.  And see it use more and more memory, that eventually crashes your program.  You'll have to go slower.  And not endlessly append text to a TextBox, you must throw old text away once in a while.

Comment: `I have this while loop in a background workers do work sub so that the controls can be updated from the background worker sub` thats not how it is supposed to work.  Do the work on the BGW and update the UI only from the UI thread.  The BGW includes a method and event for reporting progress

Answer (score 0):

It freezes because the UI thread is busy with the loop. It seems that you didn't implement the background worker properly and it is still attached to the UI thread.

You can add `DoEvents` somewhere inside your loop, which gives the UI thread some time to handle UI events. But this is just a Band-Aid fix because I don't know your code. The ideal way is to fix your background worker and its relationship with the UI thread.

Comment: Can you elaborate? What does DoEvents do, and why do you think it working help me with this problem?

Comment: Don't ever use DoEvents. Implement a proper background / threading solution to your code. @JonW

Comment: I've added the application.doevents line to my while loop, and I'm letting it run to test it out. What is the best way for me to determine the problem between my background worker thread and my ui thread, and how can I fix it?

Comment: `DoEvents` ought to be deprecated and the same function published under the name `DoEventsAndIntroduceReentrancyBugsAndDeadlocks`.

Comment: `DoEvents` fixes the problem in the same way that closing your eyes allows you to continue working when your office is on fire.

Comment: @JonW We can probably help you if you post your `BackgroundWorker` code.

Comment: My background worker code is about 10,000+ lines of code, and I'm on stack on my phone, can't really copy it here. All of my ui operations (changing textbox.text and radio button.checked) are done through code similar to the following :

`Private Sub TextBox4TextSet(text As String)

        If TextBox4.InvokeRequired = True Then

            Dim d As New TextBox4Callback(AddressOf TextBox4TextSet)

            Me.Invoke(d, New Object() {text})

        Else

            Me.TextBox4.Text = text

        End If

    End Sub`

Comment: To all commenters, I've clearly stated that the `DoEvents` was a Band-Aid and code must be fixed, so I don't understand why you're repeating the same thing in different words. Basically, if you use `DoEvents` then you might as well not bother with the background worker or anything.

Comment: @JonW We cannot help you without seeing the code. 10k+ lines in background worker means that your code is already in miserable shape and most likely needs to be rewritten from scratch. In such case, `DoEvents` might be your only way to dodge the inevitable for a little longer and start thinking about what to do with your project.